# Grails - how to access properties file from GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to have access to my properties file from GSP file to get one of it's values.
I tried to find example over the web, but I couldn't.
This is a file which I created and not Grails.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why access a file in GSP and not in a controller?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are really trying to do.  If you are trying to retrieve the value so you can render it in the page the message tag will work (see my answer below).  If you are trying to retrieve the value for some other purpose, that purpose may dictate what the best thing to do is.

Comment: It's a new .properties file which I created by myself, it located in web-app folder and I just need to read some property from it.

Answer (score 2):

From grails controller and gsp file, you can access your yml file properties using `GrailsApplication` object:

```
${grailsApplication.config.get('YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME)}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access aaplicationContext from the GSP ... so you can access any configuration property.

Just look at this entry from Mr. Haki:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/grails-goodness-get-grailsapplication.html

Answer (score 0):

If the properties file is under grails-app/i18n/ (it can be your own properties file, doesn't have to be one of the default ones) then you can access property values from the property file in a GSP using the message tag.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html.

Comment: it's not. it's under web-app folder and it's a new file which I created.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to know how you should solve this.  If these values are to be retrieved from the properties file and then rendered in a GSP, move the properties files to the i18n dir and use the message tag.  If the values are to be used for some other purpose, knowing what that purpose is will dictate what the right solution is.

Comment: Just for clarity, you can create your own property files under the i18n did and Grails will find them as long as the name ends in .properties.

Comment: I did create it. I didn't understand how do I need to use the <g:message> tag when I have a file of my own.
How do I specify my new properties file name in the tag?

Comment: You don't specify the property file name in the tag.  The name of the property file does not matter.  If you define grails-app/conf/i18n/stackoverflow.properties and in that file you have foo.bar=Winning, then in your GSP you invoke the message tag with code="foo.bar".  You never specify the name of the file.  All of those property files are loaded up and configured in the messageSource bean.

Comment: That way in stackoverflow.properties you could have "foo.bar=Winning" and in stackoverflow_es.properties you could have "foo.bar=Ganar".  In your GSP you just invoke the message tag with code="foo.bar" and the localization will work.  Even if you aren't concerned about localization, the same process works.  Just don't create localized files like stackoverflow_es.properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading simple properties it sounds like what you want is [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized)

To use it in a GSP (if you really need to, but not recommended from a GSP):

```
${Holders.config.myPropertyKey}
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to put code like that in a GSP.

Comment: This des not works for me. BTW @JeffScottBrown why it's bad idea? ... is there any difference with having the same under i18 folder (??)