# Grails - access properties for use in il8n message

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm building an app that uses il8n messages properties files for multiple languages.

However, the app must be configurable to show different client names, e.g. "View your [client app name] profile", which obviously cannot be hard-coded in il8n messages files without a generating a separate .war for each client.

One solution would be to let the client define the name in an external .properties or .groovy file, store the hard-coded il8n string as "Manage your {0} profile", and pass the name as a grails message argument, e.g.

However, replies to a similar question say calling properties from .gsps is not recommended:

[Grails - how to access properties file from GSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364829/grails-how-to-access-properties-file-from-gsp)

I know that ideally properties should be retrieved from within a controller and then passed to the view gsp, but passing client-configurable properties from every controller and view method seems excessive, especially since there will be several client-defined terms set in external .groovy or .properties files.

What then is the better/proper way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have a concept of client configuration. This should be an external configuration file. The contents of this file should be read by a service (loaded on application startup) then you can create a tag library that fetches these values (think key/value pair) from the service for use in your GSP and message codes. Using a service you can also use it elsewhere in your application as well (controllers, or other services).

That's the way you should approach this.